# Bash: sourcing file as user from script

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I am creating a script meant to be run as superuser that reads a file and runs a number of scripts on behalf of all users. The important bit is this:

```
sudo -u $user -H source /home/$user/list_of_commands
```

However, whether I encose the command with quotesor not, this fails with:

```
sudo: source /home/user/list_of_commands: command not found
```

I have even tried with the . bash builtin:

```
sudo: . /home/user/list_of_commands: command not found
```

Of course running `source` outside a `sudo` environment works. I thought there might be a `PATH` problem, and I tried to bypass it by providing the full path to `source`. However, I cannot find the executable: `which source` returns `which: no source in (/usr/local/sbin:usr/local/bin:usr/bin)`. So I'm stuck.

How do I make a script source a file as a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` is a builtin not a command, use it with `bash -c`:

```
sudo -u $user -H bash -c "source /home/$user/list_of_commands"
```